# What is the difference between Spectral Clustering and Laplacian Eigenmaps?

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, spectral-analysis, differences

It seems like [Spectral Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering) is just a term for dimension reduction via [Laplacian Eigenmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction#Laplacian_eigenmaps) + a clustering algorithm on the output.

Is this the case, or am I missing some fundamental difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though choices of [Similarity measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure#Use_in_clustering), [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Definition), and [Clustering algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cluster_analysis_algorithms) etc may differ in specific implementations, the general algorithm for Spectral Clustering is indeed identical to that of Laplacian Eigenmaps + a Clustering method:

> #### 4.6 Relation between LE and Spectral Clustering
>
> Although Laplacian Eigenmaps are oriented to dimensionality reduction algorithm and Spectral
>   Clustering is focused on cluster data, they are very related.
>
> Both methods are approaches provided by the eigenvectors of Laplacian Graphs. Specifically,
>   if we want to compare them, we must focus our attention on Normalized Spectral Clustering based
>   on Random Walks (algorithm 5). If we compare both algorithms (see comparative table 4.6.1),
>   we will see that the only difference is that Spectral Clustering makes one step more to cluster the
>   information in the new dimension.
>
> [image]

- [Advanced methods for dimensionality reduction and clustering: Laplacian Eigenmaps and Spectral Clustering](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1777/ca4bb9fe1cd0f85e24857488339eb2e6a7dc.pdf), pp.41-42 (2010)

As one can see, steps 1 - 8 are identical for both algorithms, the only difference being whether the embedding itself is returned (LE) or a clustering algorithm is applied and the clusters returned (SC).